# how to convert Htmlnode of HtmlAgilityPack to webbrowser HtmlElement

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I was creating a application that automatically inserts data into html input tags.
I have xPath for specific tag like '/html/body/form/div/div[2]/div/div/input' and I managed to get HtmlNode with the help of HtmlAgilityPack

```
var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
StringReader sr = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML);
htmlDocument.Load(sr);
    if (htmlDocument.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        HtmlNode currentNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
    }
```

Now i need to somehow select HtmlElement from Webbrowser.Document which corresponds to current HtmlNode . Can somebody help me with that?

BTW: I am not creating any spamming bot.

Hi everyone again. I found solution with recursion, lots of if statements and no htmlagilitypack, but unfortunately i can't post it right now. It seems that i don't have enough reputation.

Still, if it doesn't make too much effort, can you please tell me how to solve this problem with htmlagilitypack, because my code seems really nasty.

Comment: @MaziarBouali hi, how can i select specific htmlElement after converting Htmlnode to string?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone. After thinking and programming for a almost whole day, I came to decision that i have to use native htmlElement instead of htmlagilitypack HtmlNode, because I want to input text into Htmlelement in webbrowser . so here is the code that i came up with. still i would appreciate if someone shows a solution with htmlagilitypack.

```
    public HtmlElement selectHtmlNode(string xPath, HtmlElement htmlElement)
    {
        string currentNode;
        int indexOfElement;

        //get string representation of current Tag.
        if (xPath.Substring(1,xPath.Length-2).Contains('/'))
            currentNode = xPath.Substring(1, xPath.IndexOf('/', 1) - 1);
        else
            currentNode = xPath.Substring(1, xPath.Length-1);
        //gets the depth of current xPath
        int numOfOccurence = Regex.Matches(xPath, "/").Count;

        //gets the children's index
        int.TryParse(Regex.Match(currentNode, @"\d+").Value, out indexOfElement);

        //if i have to select nth-child ex: /tr[4]
        if (indexOfElement > 1)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.Substring(0, xPath.IndexOf('[') - 1);
            //the tag that i want to get
            if (numOfOccurence == 1 || numOfOccurence == 0)
            {
                return htmlElement.Children[indexOfElement - 1];
            }
            //still has some children tags
            if (numOfOccurence > 1)
            {
                int i = 1;
                //select nth-child
                foreach (HtmlElement tempElement in htmlElement.Children)
                {
                    if (tempElement.TagName.ToLower() == currentNode && i == indexOfElement)
                    {
                        return selectHtmlNode(xPath.Substring(xPath.IndexOf('/', 1)), tempElement);
                    }
                    else if (tempElement.TagName.ToLower() == currentNode && i < indexOfElement)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (numOfOccurence == 1 || numOfOccurence == 0)
            {
                return htmlElement.FirstChild;
            }
            if (numOfOccurence > 1)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement tempElement in htmlElement.Children)
                {
                    if (tempElement.TagName.ToLower() == currentNode)
                    {
                        return selectHtmlNode(xPath.Substring(xPath.IndexOf('/', 1)), tempElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

function is called in this way. where htmlController is instance of some class.

```
HtmlElement currentElement = htmlController.selectHtmlNode("/body/form/div/div[2]/div/div/input", webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
currentElement.SetAttribute("Value", "hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know certain position of you element you can simply get the element by

**HtmlNode mynode=htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='fooclass']");**

or you can use Select function for HtmlNodeCollection.

After getting certain node just use mynode variables Attributes,InnerHtml or InnerText properties for your needs.

for example: if your node refers an image  **mynode.Attributes["src"].Value** will show you the image source uri.

PS: I assume htmlDocument is the class of HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it. How will i get HtmlElement which is inside webbrowser.Document? can you provide with just simplest example, even if it is just /html/body?

Comment: **string html_str=webrowser.DocumentText;** as decribed http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx after you can load html_str in HtmAgilityPack HtmlDocument like **htmldoc.LoadHtml(html_str);**

Comment: I hope this covers your needs                                   string html_srt = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html_doc = new HtmlDocument();
html_doc.LoadHtml(html_srt);      html_doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fooclass']//h2//a");

Comment: I think that we have misunderstanding in my problem. What i want to do is, to automatically  type in, select, check data into webbrowser html tags. For example there is <input type="text"> and after webbrowser load, i want to type in some text into it. I tried code above, it just selects nodes, but not actual html element, which means that i cannot do anything with webbrowser. i hope that this make sense.